Next.js initialCanonicalUrl not working with basePath
I have an issue nearly identical to https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/59971, however, I am trying to solve this with next.js middleware.
We already use middleware to help with authenticated routes so this is the preferred solution.
To Reproduce

Create a Next.js app that uses a basePath (for example '/g/`) and the app router (or look at example repo from the github issue)
Create and load a page in the application (/path/testing-page in example repo)
Inspect the page and find the script with self.__next_f.push(....
Find the initialCanonicalUrl and it will be missing the base path (path).

This is causing issues with SEO because crawlers see the URL and think it's a valid URL. From what I gather, there is currently no way to properly set it. We are getting 404s from this in the Google Search Console.
My initial thought was to add the basePath manually to the url.pathname and then pass in the url into NextResponse.rewrite, however, when I do this, the url is rewritten with an additional basePath
if (
      !url.pathname.startsWith(basePath) &&
      !request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith(basePath) &&
      basePath !== '/'
    ) {
      url.pathname = `${basePath}${url.pathname}`;
      return NextResponse.rewrite(url);
    }

Removing the basePath from the url.pathname corrects the issue, but the initialCanonicalUrl remains without the basePath
